# Add/Remove Components based on enum value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a custom Inspector, and I would like to know, is there any way for me to track if an enum changes in the inspector? When It does change, I would like to add/remove components automatically based on which enum value is selected.

So for this enum:

**Within Class A**

```
public enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
};
```

**Class B (Added to the GameObject)**

```
public A.MyEnum myenum;
```

**Class: MyEditorEditor**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor(typeof(B))]
public class MyEditorEditor : Editor {
     // When A.MyEnum changes do some event
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your GUI has changed with `GUI.changed` property. Here is an example for this

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(B))]
public class TestEditor : Editor {
// your class
B b;
// holder enum to check changes
MyEnum mEnumHolder;

void OnEnable () {
    b = target as B;
    // set starting enum value
    mEnumHolder = b.myEnum;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public override void OnInspectorGUI (){
    // draw gui
    DrawDefaultInspector();
    //b.myEnum = (MyEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("My enum",b.myEnum);
    // check if gui changed
    if(GUI.changed)
    {
        // check if enum field changed
        if(b.myEnum != mEnumHolder)
        {
            // TODO  do specific action here, maybe with a switch loop
            //b.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            // set new holder
            mEnumHolder = b.myEnum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me not to draw a GUI element?

Comment: what do you mean by not drawing, if you don't call `DrawDefaultInspector` or reference your public fields in your custom editor they won't be drawn

Comment: `EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup` draws a drop down, I don't want that. I want everything drawn by `DrawDefaultInspector` and when the enum changes, I want to add a component to the gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

On your Class B - you could have your enum as a property with getters and setters.

```
private MyEnum _myEnum;

public MyEnum MyEnumProperty 
{  
    get 
    { 
       return _myEnum; 
    }
    set 
    { 
       _myEnum = value;
       UpdateMyEditor(value);
    }
 }
```

you could then put logic in the UpdateMyEditor function to notify - maybe have a look at the observer pattern for ways to do this.